# What is the meaning of “=::” in mathematics?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I've seen `=::` symbol in arithmetic series in a math YouTube video(1). I tried to google this symbol, But it is hard to find without knowing the name of this symbol.

After all I got the meaning of `=:` symbol from Wikipedia(2). `=:` is defined as; is equal by definition to.

Arithmetic series where `=::` is used-
lets take a series;

```
1+ 2+ 3 + ..... +100
```

Taking first term as F, last term as L and difference between each term is d. We can write;

```
F + (F+d) + ........ + (l-d) + l =:: A
```

What does `=::` do? Is there any difference between `=::` and `=:`?

*Resources*:

(1) [YouTube - Arithmetic Sums](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6axtBS6IF8&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60UlabZBeeqOuoLuj_KNphQ&index=67)

(2) [Wikipedia - List of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)

Comment: I've never seen that notation.  What's the reference for it?

Comment: I've never seen it either, if it is not defined in the book itself (check the index), I would assume it was most likely a typo and the author meant $=:$. After this is $A$ used as the sum of the series?

Comment: In context that looks the same as =: (meaning the left and right sides are equal and the left side is the definition of the right side).

Comment: @lulu it is also used in this video in their explanation [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6axtBS6IF8&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60UlabZBeeqOuoLuj_KNphQ&index=67]

Comment: Judging from the video it just means $=:$.

Comment: By the way, a mathematical writer should not use even the := or =: notation without defining it for the reader. I avoid it completely; the surrounding words should be perfectly adequate for informing the reader that we are defining a quantity (and if they're not, the =: doesn't completely make up for it).

Comment: @FlorisClaassens okay. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some prefer `A::=` over `A:=`, and some use it on the right, `=:A` or `=::A`.

Comment: "some use it on the right", if you mean it as a "personal preference", is slightly incorrect, they're different: you use $b:=a$ to give $b$ the value of $a$ and you use $b=:a$ to give $a$ the value of $b$

Comment: @Flutterblaxi: I didn't say that they both apply left-to-right; did I ?

Comment: I just meant that the way you phrased it might be a little confusing to someone who doesn't know the difference :)